# public_activity custom activities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, public-activity

I try to store an activity using #create_activity from the public_activity gem:

**Model**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common
end
```

**Controller**

```
def send_invitation
    @user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email])
    @user.create_activity :send_invitation, owner: @group, recipient: @user
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

**The error**

undefined method `create_activity' for #User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007febb0f0a610

Comment: You should include `PublicActivity::Common` in the User model instead of Group model.

Comment: As Bachan has mentioned see the documentation for implementing,
http://rubydoc.info/gems/public_activity/PublicActivity/Common

Answer (score 0):

Use should use
`@user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).first` instead. Without first, it return an ActiveRecord Relation as specified in the error